# Combine the result of 2 SELECT in one

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have 2 selects:

```
SELECT * 
FROM driverdetails 
WHERE driverdetails.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'

SELECT * 
FROM location 
WHERE location.utc = (  SELECT MAX(location.utc) 
                        FROM location 
                        WHERE location.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'
                    );
```

And I am trying to have a single result like: 
Columns from select1 + columns from select 2

How do I achieve the columns one after another by keeping all conditions from example?

Comment: Hi, help us to help you by showing us an example of the output you want to achieve please

Comment: Does `driverdetails.driverid` actually `==` the `location.truckid` i.e. can we JOIN on those 2 columns? or was that just an example

Comment: I modified to have same column: `driverid`

Comment: Same `driverid` column in both tables and the value must be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM driverdetails 
INNER JOIN location ON location.driverid = driverdetails.driverid
WHERE driverdetails.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'
```

On the above, you will get joined one. But as per your condition, it need a `MAX(location.utc)`

so for that, you need to create a temporary table on the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM driverdetails 
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT *,MAX(location.utc) as maxUTC 
             FROM location 
             GROUP BY location.driverid 
           ) as location_temp ON location_temp.driverid = driverdetails.driverid
WHERE driverdetails.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This is not compatible with 'sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Comment: Then use your same query with a temporary table. 
or replace sql_mode
```SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));```

Comment: ```SELECT * 
FROM driverdetails 
INNER JOIN (
                         SELECT * 
                         FROM location 
                        WHERE location.utc = (  SELECT MAX(location.utc) 
                                                                FROM location 
                                                                WHERE location.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'            )
           ) as location_temp ON location_temp.driverid = driverdetails.driverid
WHERE driverdetails.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use subselect then:

```
SELECT
     (SELECT * 
     FROM driverdetails 
     WHERE driverdetails.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'
     ),
     (SELECT * 
     FROM location 
     WHERE location.utc = (  SELECT MAX(location.utc) 
                        FROM location 
                        WHERE location.driverid = '32bbdbe8-eda0-32a5-92c0-f9215e24edcf'
     );
```

UPD: after you edited tables to match by some column, i recommend you to use the answer above

Comment: Thank you the answer, it is working great. Moreover aliases must be added after each `select`.